# Como lidar com vários parâmetros não obrigatórios em uma rota

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho a seguinte roda em um controle asp.net mvc:

```
[Route("video/categoria/{categoria}/{page?}/{sort?}")]
```

Os três parametros são: `categoria`, filtra a categoria do video, `page?` é a paginação do resultado, `sort?` é o order by da consulta, mais vistos ou mais novos.

Primeira situação: Primeira pagina de uma categoria

```
\video\categoria\comedia
```

ou

```
\video\categoria\comedia\1
```

Segunda situação: segunda pagina de uma categoria

```
\video\categoria\comedia\2
```

Vamos pegar os 3 casos e colocar a ordem, e incluir o parâmetro de ordem, foi onde tive meu primeiro problema.

```
\video\categoria\comedia\mais_vistos (Erro...)
\video\categoria\comedia\1\mais_vistos
\video\categoria\comedia\2\mais_vistos
```

Eu entendo perfeitamente que o erro vem no momento que ele tenta colocar "mais_vistos" dentro da variável page do controle.

A minha solução foi colocar em todo lugar que tiver o link com ordem o \1\ de page antes. Acredito que seja o mais correto a se fazer.
    \video\categoria\comedia\1\mais_vistos

Agora eu tenho outro problema, apareceu mais um parâmetro ao final da URL:

```
[Route("video/tag/{tag}/{page?}/{sort?}/{genero?}")]
```

Esse parametro vai funcionar como opcional e pode ser (vazio=todos, adulto, não_adulto)

Partindo do principio que eu dei a solução de colocar o \1\ de page sempre que quiser usar o parâmetro ordem, eu passo a ter os seguintes casos:

```
\video\categoria\comedia
\video\categoria\comedia\1
\video\categoria\comedia\2
\video\categoria\comedia\1\mais_vistos
\video\categoria\comedia\2\mais_vistos
```

Estou pensando em aplicar a mesma solução, só que agora tanto no parâmetro page quanto no parâmetro sort (que o default é mais_vistos):

```
\video\categoria\comedia
\video\categoria\comedia\1\mais_vistos\adulto

\video\categoria\comedia\1
\video\categoria\comedia\1\mais_vistos\adulto

\video\categoria\comedia\2
\video\categoria\comedia\2\mais_vistos\adulto

\video\categoria\comedia\1\mais_vistos
\video\categoria\comedia\1\mais_vistos\adulto

\video\categoria\comedia\2\mais_vistos
\video\categoria\comedia\2\mais_vistos\adulto
```

Essa seria a melhor solução mesmo?

Gostaria de opiniões mesmo de quem concorde com a solução, deixe pelo menos um comentário dizendo que acha a melhor sugestão.

Toda a experiencia de vocês é bem vinda.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

A rota é referente a esse metodo:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConsultaVideo(string categoria, int? page, string sort)
```

Agora ele deve ficar assim:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConsultaVideo(string categoria, int? page, string sort, string genero)
```

Comment: Pode colocar também os cabeçalhos de cada *Action* na pergunta?

Comment: Desculpa a demora, estava almoçando, pergunta editada com a assinatura da Action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando todos os parâmetros após o parâmetro nulo como obrigatórios:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConsultaVideo(string categoria, int? page, string sort, string genero)
```

No seu lugar, eu definiria um método apenas com parâmetros em *default* preenchidos, por exemplo:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConsultaVideo(string categoria, int? page = null, string sort = "mais_vistos", string genero = "todos")
```

Tendo isto, as rotas devem funcionar.

Adendo: se você **realmente** precisa usar uma rota sem preencher, melhor fazer um polimosfismo com menos parâmetros e colocar outra rota nele.

Comment: Com essa solução sua. A rota para pegar a categoria piada, página 1, mais vistos, e adulto (aqui adulto nao seria a default), seria: \video\categoria\piada\adulto ? Isso funcionária? Não ne?

Comment: Com essa solução sua. A rota para pegar a categoria piada, página 1, mais vistos, e adulto (aqui adulto nao seria a default), seria: \video\categoria\piada\adulto ? Isso funcionária? Não ne?

Comment: Não, infelizmente não dá pra pular a ordem dos atributos da rota. Se você precisa preencher gênero, precisa também preencher todos os demais.

Comment: Então é correto dizer que se eu quiser aproveitar a rota \video\categoria\ e precisar colocar o valor em genero eu sou obrigado a colocar o valor default deles na URL, certo?

Comment: Exatamente. Ou montar um polimorfismo mais simples do método com outra rota.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado, seria legal colocar esse ultimo comentário seu na resposta também, pode ser que ajude outra pessoa também.

Comment: Ok, está lá. Eu que agradeço ;)